# Getting the property value within multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Just for an example of what I am trying to do:

```
item1.item2
//item2 has four objects
//object0, object1, object2, object3
//each object has the same property within it 'propTitle'
```

I need to get the propTitle value of all 4 objects. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: `item1.item2.object0.propTitle` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var titles = $.map(item1.item2, function(v, i) {
    return v.propTitle;
});
```

---

Or without jQuery, assuming `item1.item2` is an Array...

```
var titles = item1.item2.map(function(v, i) {
    return v.propTitle;
});
```

Though you'll need a patch to support older browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility